# Pascal ABC, написать программу применя While и repeat

Tags: pascal

помогите пожалуйста
Требуется написать программу которая запрашивает числа с клавиатуры до тех пор, пока введенное число не будет больше суммы чисел или количество чисел не превысит 10
Вот код написанный
Но там почему-то игнорирует условие что если число веденное превысит сумму чисел то завершить прогу?
Помогите если знаете причину этого

```
program Project1;
var
  Chislo: real;
  Count: longint;
  sum: real;
begin
  Count:= 0;
  {sum:= 0;}
  writeln('Введите числа: ');
  repeat
    readln(Chislo);
    inc(Count);
    sum:= sum + chislo;
  until (Chislo > sum) or (Count > 10);
  writeln('Программа закончила работу, сумма:',sum);
  readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sum := 0;
writeln('Введите числа: ');
repeat
  sum := sum + chislo;
  readln(Chislo);
  inc(Count);
until ( (Chislo > sum) and (Count > 1) ) or (Count > 10);
```

Comment: Все равно также)

Comment: Всё отлично заработало)

Comment: @IlyaFilimonov Очень хорошо. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: Спасибо большое))

Comment: А чему равно chislo в первой итерации цикла?...

Comment: @Alekcvp в первой итерации цикла `chislo` равно `sum`